# Slide component like Kindle app?

Tags: android

I intend to write an Android app for reading books. I can't find an component to slide the pages like Kindle app. Where can I find the sample code of that component?

A slide component like this.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9jmCk3K3YT8&t=1m33s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The view you need is called a ViewPager

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/577

Answer (score 1):

Second thing you can write, extend Horizontal ScrollView, and now overwrite onTouch(MotionEvent e);
you need to get action of e, so if e.getAction=MotionEvent.ACTION_UP check scroll position, and than scroll to closer edge. You can define edges by screenWidth.

If you want to make swipe action, so you need to implement gestrue listener